# Grab top 5 from a list based on highest value

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list which is made up of two items postcode and totalCost. I want to grab the top 5 items from this list which have the highest total cost. I have tried

```
var top5 = list.Take(5).OrderByDescending(a => a.TotalCost);
```

also

```
var top5 = list.OrderByDescending(a=> a.TotalCost).Take(5);
```

Neither of these queries produce anything in var called top5. What is wrong with this syntax please?

Comment: What is the type of `list` in this scene? how it looks like?

Comment: The list has been declared as   List<PostCodeSum> postCodeSumTotals = new List<PostCodeSum>();

Comment: The PostCodeSum class only contains  private decimal _totalCost;
        private string _postCode;

Comment: Could you add some more code? 'Cause if the surrounding code is OK, it seems to me something like this should work:

var top5 = list.OrderByDescending(x => x.totalCost).Take(5);

Unless of course the list is actually a query expression towards a database and you dispose the contet before calculating the Top 5: then the list will stay empty. To solve, add a call to ToList()

Comment: Obviously list in the statement above is substituted with postCodeSumTotals.Take etc...I can see that the list is populated correctly in debug mode right before using my LINQ statement.

Comment: When you run your second query, what is the output that you get?

Comment: The methods are executed in order. When you do `.Take(5).OrderByDescending(...)`, you first take the first 5 items and then order those 5. You want to order first and *then* Take(5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 var i = sums.OrderByDescending(x => x.TotalCost).Take(5).ToList();

    foreach (var postCodeSum in i)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(postCodeSum.TotalCost);
    }
```

EDIT: Didn't realise you wanted the highest values, edited the code; I've ran the code and it should work just fine.

Comment: No still no joy with the above.  If I hover over sums i.e. the list in debug mode, I can see that the list is populated with values, however it doesn't extract anything to the variable.

Comment: Default OrderBy is ascending. It will fetch the first five least cost data.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot the .ToList as you state above.

Answer (score 1):

LINQ can be used :

```
.OrderByDescending(x => x.TotalCost).Take(5).ToList();
```

The problem is the .ToList() you forgot.

Answer (score 0):

The supplied query(`OrderByDescending` followed by `Take()`)should work, make sure that the property/fileds in the class are public. I'm answering based on the comment

> *The PostCodeSum class only contains private decimal _totalCost; private string _postCode; – Giraffe 4 m*

If it is private as you mentioned you will definitely get compilation error at `a.TotalCost` in the query. if the properties are accessible means the following code will work:

```
var top5 = postCodeSumTotals.OrderByDescending(a => a.TotalCost).Take(5);
```

Take a look at this [Working Example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/2gT90J)

Answer (score 0):

Resolved it by putting the result into a list instead. Not sure why the other way didn't work.

```
List<PostCodeSum> postCodeSumTotalsFinal = postCodeSumTotals.OrderByDescending(o => o.TotalCost).Take(5).ToList();
```

Comment: To answer why this happens: When you use Linq, your commands do not get executed immediately upon calling them. What happens is that Linq builds an `IQueryable` object, which basically stockpiles your commands (Select, OrderBy, ...). It is only **when you try to access the resulting values** that Linq will actually _execute_ the stockpiled commands on your source list. By calling `.ToList()`, you are triggering this behavior (because it makes a list from the elements, which means that Linq needs to know which elements they are, which means the commands must be executed). Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, much appreciated.